# Keep differences between two hashtables

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, hashtable

I am making a function that compares two hashtables and I want to keep the difference of these tables. So if they both contain 100 keys and only 2 have been altered I want a new hashtable to equal only those 2 differences.

Here is what I have. I really am lost on how to do the (keep differences)

```
private Hashtable CompareHashtables(Hashtable ht1, Hashtable ht2)
{
    Hashtable ResultsOfCompare = new Hashtable();
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ht1)
    {
        if (ht2.ContainsKey(entry.Key) && ht2.ContainsValue(entry.Value) == false)
        {
            //Keep differences

        }
    }
    return ResultsOfCompare;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to check both the key and the value for equality.  If both don't match then it's considered a difference.  This creates a bit of a problem for you because that type of difference can't be represented in a hash table.  Consider the following

- ht1: key = `"bob"` value = `42`
- ht2: key = `"bob"` value = `13`

Here the key is the same but the value is difference.  To store every difference the resulting structure would need to be able to contain 2 different values for the same key.  That's not really possible with `Hashtable`.  An `ArrayList` of the entries that differ may be a better choice for this exercise.

Really there are 3 cases to consider

1. Both tables contain the same key but have different values
2. Left table has the key but not right
3. Right table has the key but not left

Items 2 and 3 can be collapsed together but it's harder to collapse 1 into this bag. You probably need another data structure to instruct you about the difference in the table

```
struct Difference { 
  internal readonly bool IsValueDifferent; 
  internal readonly object Key;
  internal readonly object Value;
  internal readonly object OtherValue;

  internal Difference(object key, object value) { 
    Key = key;
    Value = value;
    IsValueDifferent = false;
  }

  internal Difference(object key, object value, object otherValue) { 
    Key = key;
    Value = value;
    OtherValue = otherValue;
    IsValueDifferent = true;
  }
}
```

With this you can represent the cases.

```
private Hashtable CompareHashtables(Hashtable ht1, Hashtable ht2) {
  ArrayList diffList = new ArrayList();
  foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ht1) {
    object value = ht2[entry.Key];
    if (value == null) { 
      diffList.Add(new Difference(entry.Key, entry.Value));
    } else if (!value.Equals(entry.Value)) {
      diffList.Add(new Difference(entry.Key, entry.Value, value));
    }
  }

  foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ht2) {
    object value = ht1[entry.Key];
    if (value == null) {
      diffList.Add(new Difference(entry.Key, entry.Value));
    }
  }

  return diffList;
}
```

Note: `Hashtable` and `ArrayList` are essentially deprecated at this point.  Why not use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `List<T>` instead?

Comment: Just giving an update. I did end up switching over to using a Dictionary and it worked perfectly. Had a bit of a headache getting it all set up and the logic and all but once I got it, it was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If both hashtables contain the key and value either

1. Remove the value from one of the hashtables you wish to keep as the result (this way you will remove all duplicates). This will only use 2 hashtables but it will also ruin the data from one of the tables.
2. Store every negative evaluation of this requirement in a third hashtable you will use as result. This will use a total of 3 hashtables but will not remove the original data.

Example using method 2:

```
private Hashtable CompareHashtables(Hashtable ht1, Hashtable ht2){
    Hashtable resultsOfCompare = new Hashtable();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in ht1) {
        if (!(ht2.ContainsKey(entry.Key) && ht2.ContainsValue(entry.Value))) {
            resultsOfCompare.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
    return resultsOfCompare;
}
```

Edit: 
as another answer remarked: you cannot store the same key twice in a resulting hashtable. I was under the impression that you would store the data of one hashtable into the resulting one, which means you can still use my method.

However if you want to keep both entries then you will have to look for a different structure.

Comment: That sounds crazy enough to work but how would I go about that. would I do IF(they equal each other)
{
  remove from hashtable 2
}
results = hashtable 3

I am just lost at how to do that code wise. Like what is going to help me here

Comment: @NitroFrost: I have added a quick example for the second method. It really is as easy as it sounds, just translate the sentences to code. If you want the first option, you'll have to use an iterator to avoid concurrentModification exceptions.

Comment: I have been on coding since 8am and its 833pm right now. Thanks so much man. Brain is fried.

Comment: I think this has the problem mentioned by @JaredPar.

Comment: @JamesPoulose: it has, I have added a small remark to this at the end.